# Java 8 stream groupingBy object field with object as a key

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following structure of classes (given example is meaningless, I've made it just for the question purposes):

```
public class ManufacturerDto {
    private String name;
    private Boolean withConfirmation;

    //getters and setters omitted for brevity
}

public class CarDto {

    private ManufacturerDto manufacturer;

    //getters and setters omitted for brevity
}

public abstract class VehicleDto {

    private list<CarDto> cars = new ArrayList<>();

    //getters and setters omitted for brevity
}

public class EuropeanMarketCarDto extends VehicleDto {

    public Map<String, List<CarDto>> getCarManufacturerToCarsMap() {

       return this.getCarDtos()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.manufacturer().getName()));

        //getters and setters omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

In the given scenario, `groupingBy` returns pretty much everything I want, but I have a problem with the key. In `getCarManufacturerToCarsMap()` method I would like to have a `manufacturer` object as a key but I am not even sure if that is possible using `groupingBy`. What can I do, to return a map of `Map<Manufacturer, List<CarDto>>` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you actually want to avoid having the map key as a `String` i.e. `Map<String, List<CarDto>>` and instead have a `Map<Manufacturer, List<CarDto>>` you can group by as follows:

```
this.getCarDtos()
      .stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getManufacturer()));
```

Note that this would require you to override `equals` and `hashcode` method in your `Manufacturer` class defining that two given objects are equal if they have the same name.

Comment: I did override. But I can't handle sorting. It doesn't want to work `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getManufacturer().getProductionDateInInstant()))` (I am getting a field of type `Instant`)

Comment: @user3529850 please post a new question. make sure to include your attempt stating what is not working, if I have time i will give it a look.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
Map<Manufacturer, List<Car>> listing = cars.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getManufacturer));
```

So, this will group all cars by it's manufacturers, ouput would be something like:

TOYOTA=[AURIS params of AURIS, AVIA params of AVIA], MERCEDES=[S500 params of 
S500... ]

**EDIT 2**

```
public class Main {

    List<Car> listOfCars = new ArrayList<>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Car> listOfCars = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfCars.add(new Car(new Manufacturer("Toyota"), "Toyota A"));
    listOfCars.add(new Car(new Manufacturer("Toyota"), "Toyota B"));
    listOfCars.add(new Car(new Manufacturer("Jeep"), "Jeep A"));
    listOfCars.add(new Car(new Manufacturer("Mercedes"), "Mercedes C"));
    listOfCars.add(new Car(new Manufacturer("Toyota"), "Toyota C"));
    listOfCars.add(new Car(new Manufacturer("Audi"), "Audi A"));
    listOfCars.add(new Car(new Manufacturer("Toyota"), "Toyota C"));



 Map<String,List<Car>> listOfCarsByManufacturers = listOfCars.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d->d.getManufacturer().getName()));

    System.out.println(listOfCarsByManufacturers);
    }




}

    public class Car {

    private Manufacturer manufacturer;
    private String nameOfTheCar;

    public Car() {
    }

    public Car(Manufacturer manufacturer, String nameOfTheCar) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.nameOfTheCar = nameOfTheCar;
    }

    public Manufacturer getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public String getNameOfTheCar() {
        return nameOfTheCar;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Manufacturer: " + getManufacturer() + ", name: " + getNameOfTheCar();
    }

}

public class Manufacturer {

    private String name;

    public Manufacturer() {
    }

    public Manufacturer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }


}
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
Map<String,List<Car>> listOfCarsByManufacturers = listOfCars.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d->d.getManufacturer().getName()));
System.out.println(listOfCarsByManufacturers);
```

Comment: How do I know, that `Car::getManufacturer` groups by `name` field and not other field in `ManufacturerDto ` (like f.e. `withConfirmation`) ?

Comment: It groups by Manufacturer, not by name or whatever.. This particulalry will be called smt like Manufacturer. toString = [all cars]

Comment: If you want a name only of the Manufacturer, take a look at edit 3.

Comment: I think, your edit2 is correct as long as I provide `toString()` method (in `manufacturer`) with a field I want to group by. The problem with edit3 is that It gives me a key of type `String`, and that's what I wanted to avoid (as I was thinking how to get an object - `manufacturer` in this case). Thanks, I appreciate it.